# Cross-Thread not valid

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to do serial communication in VB.NET but I have this error:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'TextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub SerialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles sp.DataReceived
    Dim str As String = sp.ReadExisting()
    TextBox1.Text = str
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use global variable after completed thread invoke new method

```
Dim xStr as string=string.Empty

Private Sub SerialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e 
As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles sp.DataReceived
    xStr=  sp.ReadExisting()
    Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Display))
End Sub

Private Sub Display ()
     TextBox1.Text=xStr
end sub
```

Comment: you dont know how much you helped me!

Answer (score 0):

The `DataReceived` event is on a different thread than the UI thread so accessing controls is forbidden. You can use a lambda sub inside the Invoke method so you can access controls directly since we are back on the UI thread in here.

```
Private Sub SerialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles sp.DataReceived
  Me.Invoke(Sub()
              Textbox1.Text = sp.ReadExisting()
            End Sub)
End Sub
```